# Scala constructor signature

Tags: scala, constructor, abstract-class, abstract

Is it possible to define constructor signature in Scala ?

```
abstract class A {
    def this (s: String): this.type // doesn't work
    def this (i: Int): this.type    // doesn't work
    def this (d: Double): this.type // doesn't work
}

class B(var s: String) extends A {
    def this(i: Int) = {
        this("int "+i.toString())
    }
    def this(d: Double) = {
        this("double "+d.toString())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you want, as pointed out by other answer, but one approach is to use a factory:

```
trait Foo { 
  // methods you need
}

trait FooCompanion[T <: Foo] {
  // these methods replace constructors in your example
  def apply(s: String): T
  def apply(i: Int): T
  ...
}
```

Implementation:

```
class Bar(s: String) extends Foo {
  ...
}

object Bar extends FooCompanion[Bar] {
  def apply(s: String) = new Bar(s)
  ...
}
```

and you can have methods taking `FooCompanion`. This pattern is used e.g. in the Scala collections library.

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to achieve? You can do like this:

```
abstract class A(i: Int)

case class B(s: String) extends A(s.toInt) {
  def this(i: Int) = {
    this(i.toString)
  }

  def this(d: Double) = {
    this(d.toString)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
B("1")
new B(1)
new B(1.0)
```

Comment: The abstract class is used as an interface.

Comment: If you are trying to guarantee that your class has a one argument Int constructor - it is not possible

Comment: Saying "the abstract class is used as an interface" is nonsensical. Traits in Scala and interfaces in Java have very different use restrictions than abstract classes (in either language).

Comment: Ok, but the problem is the same with traits instead of abstract classes here, right ? I could write a more detailed example of what I'm trying to achieve if need.

Comment: Traits may not have constructor arguments at all. This is not to be confused with them not having constructors, 'cause they do, just that those constructors can take no arguments.

Comment: @serejja, could you explain how could we extend this approach if we require several other constructor (not just a single one).

Comment: Thanks. The idea is that extending A ensures that we have three constructors, (eg from String, Int or Double). Here, we only ensure the Int one.

Answer (score 2):

No that is not possible. Constructors are special: You need to write `new X()` instead of `X()`, and there is no polymorphic dispatch, e.g. you cannot do `def test[A]() = new A()`. So there is no scenario in which an abstract constructor would make any sense.